# I can simply bypass Win7 Logon by pressing the power button?

Tags: windows-7, login

I just noted something VERY odd. After leaving work yesterday, I just locked my PC to have it do some work over night. When I came to office this morning, I accidentally pressed the power button on my pc (intending to turn it on, having forgotten that it still was on).

What happened next was, that the monitor turned on, showing me the login screen, which then disappeared by magic showing me the "Windows still has to stop these programs before shutdown" dialog.

I simply pressed "Cancel" in this dialog and was able to continue working without ever entering my password. This is a MASSIVE leak?!

**I just wondered if this "bug" is known and if there's a fix for it or whatever.** I know that Windows Logon is by no means secure but THIS is beyond what I expected.

Comment: I presume your workstation has all the latest windows updates? I've seen that behaviour with third party security tools, but I've never experienced it in a standard Windows build.

Comment: yes, last windows update check was performed today. May be though that some windows updates are blocked by our IT - though I very much doubt it. What third party tools are you getting at? AV?

Comment: No, specifically ones that replaced the standard Windows Logon. EG - our school computers had system management and login handled by software by a company called RM. Found out if you opened word, tried to shut down the machine it would get stuck asking if you wanted to save your word document, but closed down a number of services etc. Could then logon as an admin and do whatever you wanted. But that's irrelevant in this situation I'm sure :)

Comment: To my knowledge, this is indeed a security bug present in windows 7. I'm not sure it still exists in 10 though.